# Is it possible to showcase legends for g.raphael bar chart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raphael, graphael

I have been working with g.raphael  graphs lately,but couldn't find a solution to a particular problem where i want to show bar chart legends outside the bar chart(like one that is available in google graphs),am talking about legends here,not labels,can anybody please help me out?